# Generating random matrices for VAR(p) in PyMC3

Tags: python, theano, pymc3

I am trying to build a simple VAR(p) model using pymc3, but I'm getting some cryptic errors about incompatible dimensions. I suspect the issue is that I'm not properly generating random matrices. Here is an attempt at VAR(1), any help would be welcome:

```
# generate some data
y_full = numpy.zeros((2,100))
t = numpy.linspace(0,2*numpy.pi,100)
y_full[0,:] = numpy.cos(5*t)+numpy.random.randn(100)*0.02
y_full[1,:] = numpy.sin(6*t)+numpy.random.randn(100)*0.01
y_obs = y_full[:,1:]
y_lag = y_full[:,:-1]
with pymc3.Model() as model:
  beta= pymc3.MvNormal('beta',mu=numpy.ones((4)),cov=numpy.ones((4,4)),shape=(4))
  mu = pymc3.Deterministic('mu',beta.reshape((2,2)).dot(y_lag))
  y = pymc3.MvNormal('y',mu=mu,cov=numpy.eye(2),observed=y_obs)
```

Comment: By the way: There is no reason to use `MvNormal` instead of `Normal` if the covariance is a diagonal matrix. Also, `np.ones((4,4))` isn't positive definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line should be

```
y = pm.MvNormal('y',mu=mu.T, cov=np.eye(2),observed=y_obs.T)
```

`MvNormal` interprets the last dimension as the mvnormal vectors. This is because the behaviour of numpy indexing implies that `y_obs` is a vector of length 2 containing vectors of length 100 (`y_lag[i].shape == (100,)`)